# A problem with a quadric contained in a hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j+2\sum_{i=1}^n b_i x_i+c$ for $x\in \mathbb R^n$ where the coefficients $a_{ij},b_i,c$ are real, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and not all $a_{ij}$ are equal zero. Let
$$
Q:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n : f(x)=0\}
$$
 Let us assume that a $Q$ is contained in the set
$$
H=\{x\in \mathbb R^n: x_n=0\}.
$$

How to prove that $Q$ has to be an affine subspace (possible empty) of $\mathbb R^n$?

Thanks

Comment: $f(x)$ is a constant function as it is now, modifying it to a polynomial may make this question more in line with the title

Comment: Excuse me, surely I do not understand the question, if $f(x)=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$, then $Q=\{0\}\subset H$, but $Q$ is point, not the whole hyperplane. Have I misunderstood your question or what do you mean by an affine set?

Comment: @user90189 I wrote by mistake "affine set" instead of "affine subspace" of $\mathbb R^n$. It is an empty set or a set of the form $u+L$, where $L$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $u$ is a fixed element of $\mathbb R^n$. The set from your comments -a point-is obviously an affine subspace.

Comment: I propose the following proof. If the locus of $f$ is not empty, by an affine transformation, suppose that $f(0)=0$ and write $f(vt,t)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. By the hypotheses, $f(vt,t)=g(v)t^2$ and $g(v)\neq 0$ for every $v$. By expanding $f(vt,t)=\sum_{i,j<n}a_{i,j}v_iv_jt^2+\cdots$ and comparing with $g$, you conclude that $b_i=0$ and that $a_{i,j}$ for $i,j<n$ is positive definite, then $f(x',0)=\sum_{i,j<n}a_{i,j}x_ix_j$, and the locus of $f$ is necessarily and affine subspace, since after affine transformation $f(x',0)=x_1^2+\cdots+x_k^2$.

Comment: The $a_{ij}$ for $i,j<n$ may also be negative definite, but this doesn't change the conclusion.

Comment: @user90189 I don't understand why $f(vt,t)=g(v)t^2$ provided $f(0)=c=0$.

Comment: Dear @Alex Ravsky, I didn't think in the possibility of $f(tv,t)=h(v)t$. My reasoning was: since $Q\subset H$, we have that $f(x',x_n)\neq 0$ for $x_n\neq 0$, so $P_v(t)=f(tv,t)\neq 0$ for $t\neq 0$ and I thought that $P_v(t)=g(v)t^2$. Let my try to amend: I only know that $\text{deg}P_v\le 2$, so what I can say is $P_v(t)=g(v)t^2+h(v)t$, and $g(v)$ and $h(v)$ cannot be simultaneously neither equal 0 nor different from 0. Hence, if $h\neq 0$ then $g=0$ (because $h\neq 0$ in an open set), but in this case every $a_{ij}=0$. Am I right or are these nosenses? Thank  you.

Comment: @user90189 I got your idea, it looks interesting. It is much shorter and smarter than my canonical answer. But it has problems. First, I am not sure that we can achieve $f(0)=0$ after an affine transformation preserving the condition  that zeroes of $f$ are contained in the hyperplane $x_n=0$, which we need to exploit the claim $f(tv,t)\ne 0$ for $t\ne 0$. Next, why the quadric $a_{i,j}$ for $i,j<n$ is definite? Its value on $v$ doesn’t equal $g(v)\ne 0$, the latter is $a_{n,n}+2\sum_{i=1} a_{i,n}$ bigger.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, if $f(y,0)=0$, then you can take $\tilde{f}(x',x_n)=f(x'+y,x_n)$. We have also $g(v)=\sum_{i,j<n}a_{ij}v_iv_j+2\sum_{i<n}a_{in}v_i+a_{nn}\neq 0$ for every $v$. If $a_{ij}$ were not "semi"-definite, then $g$ should be zero at some point. Besides, we have $f(x',0)=\sum_{i,j<n}a_{i,j}x_ix_j=\pm(y_1^2+\cdots + y_r^2)$.

Comment: To be precise, I should write "If $a_{i,j}$, for $i,j<n$, were not..."

Comment: The case $r=0$, i.e. $a_{ij}=0$ for $i,j<n$, is not excluded.

Comment: @user90189 I do not have checked the all details, but this is interesting and the result looks plausible. So I think you can post a respective answer (and I’ll upvote it :-) ).

Comment: Many thanks all for nice answers, comments, explanations.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT 2. We show that $f(x)=\pm ((f_1(x))^2+\cdots+(f_k(x))^2+ux_n^2)$ where $u>0$ and the $f_i$ are affine. In particular, the form $f(x)=\pm ux_n$ is impossible because the matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ is not zero.

Proof. Let $y=(x_i)_{i\leq n-1}$. Then $f(x)=f_1(y)+ux_n^2+x_nf_2(y)$ where $f_1$ has degree $2$ and $f_2$ has degree $1$.

Case 1. $u=0$. Assume that there is $y_0$ s.t. $f_1(y_0)\not=0$. If $f_2(y_0)=0$, then $Q$ is empty. If $f_2(y_0)\not=0$, then there is a solution $x_n\not=0$, a contradiction. Thus $f_1=0$ and $f(x)=x_nf_2(y)$.

If there is $y_0$ s.t. $f_2(y_0)=0$, then there is a non-zero solution in $x_n$, a contradiction. Thus $f_2$ is a constant $a\not=0$ and $f(x)=ax_n$, that is contradictory because the matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]$ is not zero.

Case 2. $u\not=0$. For example $u>0$. If there is $y_0$ s.t. $f_1(y_0)<0$, then $f(y_0,0)<0$ and $f(y_0,x_n)>0$ for $x_n>0$ large enough, that is contradictory.

Then $f_1\geq 0$. Let $g(y,z)$ be homogeneous of degree $2$ s.t. $g(y,1)=f_1(y)$; if $z\not=0$, then $g(y,z)=z^2g(y/z,1)\geq0$; since $g(y,0)=0$, we deduce that $g\geq0$ and can be decomposed in a sum of squares of linearly independent forms $g=\sum_ig_i^2$; finally  $f_1(y)=g_1(y,1)^2+\cdots+g_k(y,1)^2$ where the $g_i(y,1)=h_i(y)$ are linearly independent affine functions. Note that at most one $h_i$ may be a constant. Let $H=(h_i)$.

Now $f(x)=h_1^2(y)+\cdots+h_k^2(y)+ux_n^2+x_nf_2(y)$. If there is $y_0$ s.t. $\Delta(y_0)=f_2^2(y_0)-4u(\sum_i h_i^2(y_0))>0$, then there are two distinct solutions in $x_n$, a contradiction. Thus $\Delta\leq 0$ -in particular $f\geq 0$-. If $\Delta(y)<0$, then no solution in $x_n$. If $\Delta(y)=0$, then, necessarily,  there is a double solution $x_n=0$, that is, $f_2(y)=0,h_i(y)=0$.

Since $h_1(y)=\cdots=h_k(y)=0$ implies that $f_2(y)=0$, there is a vector $\Lambda=(\lambda_i)$ s.t. $f_2=\sum_i \lambda_ih_i$. Thus $(\sum_i\lambda_ih_i)^2\leq4u\sum_ih_i^2$, that is, $(<\Lambda,H>)^2\leq4u||H||^2$ and, more precisely: for every $H\not=0$, $(<\Lambda,H>)^2< 4u||H||^2$. Since the affine functions $(h_i)$ are linearly independent, the previous condition is equivalent to $||\Lambda||^2<4u$.

Therefore $f(x)=h_1^2(y)+\cdots+h_k^2(y)+ux_n^2+x_n\sum_i\lambda_ih_i(y)=\sum_i (h_i(y)+(\lambda_i/2)x_n)^2+x_n^2(u-\sum_i\lambda_i^2/4)$

and we are done. $\square$

Answer (score 4):

By the affine classification of quadrics (see, for instance, [ER, Chapter X.8] the surface $Q$ is affinely equivalent to one of the following quadrics $Q’$:

(1) $\pm x_1^2\pm x_2^2\pm \dots \pm x_r^2=1$ ($1\le r\le n$)

(2) $\pm x_1^2\pm x_2^2\pm \dots \pm x_r^2=0$ ($1\le r\le n$)

(3) $\pm x_1^2\pm x_2^2\pm \dots \pm x_r^2-2x_n=0$ ($1\le r\le n-1$)

The corresponding affine map transforms $H$ to a hyperplane $H’$ determined by an equation

(4) $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots +a_nx_n=b$ or $(a,x)=b,$

where $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\ne 0$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product.

It remains assuming $Q’\subset H’$ to fulfill a simple but a bit long case check.

If the considered case is fixed, by $I^+$ (resp. $I^-$, $I^0$) we denote the set of indices $i$ such that the coefficient in the monomial of the variable $x_i$ in the equation is positive (resp. negative, zero). Also for each $1\le i\le n$ let $e_i$ denotes the standard $i$-th ort in $\Bbb R^n$, that is the vector whose all coordinates are zeroes except $i$-th, which is $1$.

(1) Since $a\ne 0$, there exists $a_i\ne 0$.

Assume that $i\in I^+$. Then both points $e_i$ and $-e_i$ satisfy equality 1. So they both satisfy equality 4 and then $$b=(a,e_i)=(a,-e_i)=-(a,e_i)=a_i=0,$$ a contradiction.

Assume that the set $Q’$ is non-empty. This implies the set $I^+$ is non-empty. Pick any index $j\in I^+$. By the above, $a_j=0$.

Assume that $i\in I^0$. Then a point $e_i+e_j$ satisfies equality 1. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a, e_i+e_j)=a_i+a_j=a_i=0,$$ 
a contradiction.

Thus $i\in I^-$. Then a point $e_i+\sqrt{2}e_j$ satisfies equality 1. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a, e_i+\sqrt{2}e_j)=a_i+\sqrt{2}a_j=a_i=0,$$ 
a contradiction.

Therefore the set $Q’$ is empty.

(2) Since $a\ne 0$, there exists $a_i\ne 0$.

Assume that $i\in I^0$. Then a point $\lambda e_i$ satisfies equality 2 for each real $\lambda$. Then $$b=(a,\lambda e_i)=\lambda a_i.$$
Since both $a_i$ and $b$ are constant, $a_i=b=0$, a contradiction.

Thus without loss of generality we may assume that $i\in I^+$.  Assume that the set $I^-$ is non-empty. Pick an arbitrary index $j\in I^-$. Both points $e_1+e_i$ and $-(e_1+e_i)$ satisfy equality 2. So they both satisfy equality 4 and then $$b=(a,e_i+e_j)=(a,-(e_i+e_j))=-(a,e_i+e_j)=a_i+a_j=0.$$
But a point $e_1-e_i$ also satisfies equality 2 . So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$0=b=(a,e_i-e_j)=a_i-a_j.$$ Thus $a_i=a_j=0$, a contradiction.

Therefore the set $I^-$ is empty and thus $$Q’=\{x: x_j=0\mbox{ for each } j\in I^+\}.$$

(3) Since $a\ne 0$, there exists $a_i\ne 0$.

Assume that $i\in I^0$. Then a point $\lambda e_i$ satisfies equality 3 for each real $\lambda$. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a,\lambda e_i)=\lambda a_i.$$
Since both $a_i$ and $b$ are constant, $a_i=b=0$, a contradiction.

Assume that $i\in I^+\setminus\{n\}$. Then a point $2\lambda e_i+2\lambda^2 e_n$ satisfies equality 3 for each real $\lambda$. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a, 2\lambda e_i+2\lambda^2 e_n)=2\lambda a_i+2\lambda^2 a_n.$$
Since $a_i$, $a_n$ and $b$ are constant, $a_i=a_n=b=0$, a contradiction.

Assume that $i\in I^-\setminus \{n\}$. Then a point $2\lambda e_i-2\lambda^2 e_n$ satisfies equality 3 for each real $\lambda$. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a, 2\lambda e_i-2\lambda^2 e_n)=2\lambda a_i-2\lambda^2 a_n.$$
Since $a_i$, $a_n$ and $b$ are constant, $a_i=a_n=b=0$, a contradiction.

Finally, assume that $i=n$. If $1\in I^+$ then put $\varepsilon=1$, otherwise (that is, if  $1\in I^-$) put $\varepsilon=-1$. Then a point $2\lambda e_1+2\varepsilon \lambda^2 e_n$ satisfies equality 3 for each real $\lambda$. So it satisfies equality 4 and then $$b=(a, 2\lambda e_1+2\varepsilon\lambda^2 e_n)=2\lambda a_1+2\varepsilon\lambda^2 a_n.$$
Since $a_1$, $a_n$ and $b$ are constant, $a_1=a_n=b=0$, a contradiction.

Thus case 3 cannot hold.

References

[ER] N.V. Efimov, E.R. Rozendorn, *Linear algebra and high-dimensional geometry* (in Russian)